# Master Theorem but with 2 different T's from two different recurrent trees

Tags: algorithms

I am studying the Master Theorem, but there is a case in which I have no knowledge on how one should proceed. If it's given:

$T_1(n)= 1$ if n=1

$T_1(n)= 4T_1(\frac n2) + \sqrt{3n}+1$ otherwise.

For this case $T_1(n) \in \Theta(n^2)$

We then have:

$T_2(n)= 1$ if n=1

$T_2(n)= 14T_2(\frac n4)+ T_1(n)=14T_2(\frac n4)+4T_1(\frac n2) + \sqrt{3n}+1$ otherwise.

If I'd like to define a,b,c how do I proceed?

Is the number of nodes in a layer for the recurrence tree  18 ?

I am unfamiliar with how one proceeds in this case.

Comment: From the first part you already know $T_1(n) = \theta(n^2)$ thus: $T_2(n) = 14T_2(n/4) + \theta(n^2)$. Now you can apply the Master Theorem.

Comment: @plshelp You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @plshelp That's what I did but there is a contradiction when I try to find the asymptotic behavior for this

Comment: When solving the second equation, $T_1$ is already known (at least asymptotically).